# Recent captured file event interception on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-camera

What i wanna do is simply add log line with file name which was recently captured. Unfortunately, application fails because of below indicated error. Code and error from stack provided below.

Thanks in advance,

Anar

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity
>   {az.justx.justx/az.justx.justx.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object
>   reference

```
private void interceptCameraButtonClick() {

    Button cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cam);

    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
                    imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
                    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "AD_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
                    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
                    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 100);
                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i("Test", Integer.toString(resultCode));

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Log.i("CALLED", "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getData());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are passing uri while creating intent so you won't get it in data.getData(). You have to use that URI directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement that the camera send back the `Uri` in the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`. You already know what the `Uri` is, as you put it in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. You just need to use that value. Be sure to include it in your saved instance state, as your process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground.